# Dev Express WPF GridControl - Auto-downsize behavior

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a DX GridControl in a * height row, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>​
...​
    <Grid x:Name="ContainingGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <dxg:GridControl Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ContainingGrid}">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
...
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This works great - the row renders, gets a definite ActualHeight, and the Grid's Height is bound to this, thereby avoiding the need to specify the AllowInfinite​GridSize property.

However, this is all contained in a re-sizable module. When I make this module bigger, the Grid grows with it, and the GridControl grows with the Grid, as I was hoping/expecting. However, when I re-size the module to be smaller, the GridControl's Height stays at the bigger value.

I'm thinking an attached behavior but unsure of what I should do in it. Any suggestions for how to get the GridControl to resize downwards to match its container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce this issue, but all works fine on my side. I think you have something additional in your code, which causes this issue.
I cannot also understand why you do this binding. The GridControl will be resized correctly without this binding.
Take special note that the GridControl does nothing with its Height. If you change the GridControl to a standard Button, this button will work like the grid.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for responding here. The controls are contained in a module within a layout manager that is built on the Syncfusion layout manager. I'll investigate further to see if this is causing the issue.

Comment: Oh BTW, the reason for the Binding to ActualHeight is to avoid the InfiniteGridSize exception. Given your surprise at this, I guess this may also be related to the layout manager...

Comment: As I can see, your layout is more complex than you wrote in your first message. That is why I am afraid I need more detailed information about your layout structure. I suggest you create a new ticket with this question in our [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) and provide that information there. If you attach a test sample, it will be very helpful for us.

Comment: Alex - will do when I get time to package up a good working example, maybe not be immediate though... conflicting priorities here. :)